# Facebook posting to page as page using PHP API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to set up a script to automatically post a message to a Facebook page I am admin of. I have the code below but currently, instead of posting to the page's wall as the page admin, the post is going to the "visitor posts" section of the page from my personal account. Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

```
require_once('Facebook/autoload.php');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'myappid',
  'app_secret' => 'myappsecret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$pageID = 'mypageid';
$accessToken = 'myaccesstoken';

try {
  $publish = $fb->post('/' . $pageID . '/feed', 
     array(
       'access_token' => $accessToken,
       'message' => $status,
       'to' => $pageID
       )
   );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the page's access token, not your personal one.

Using your personal access token, call `/me/accounts`. It'll give you a list of pages you're an administrator of, and access tokens for each one.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have swapped out the access token with the one I found associated with the page in the API Explorer using `/me/accounts` but now I am getting the error: `Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument` I checked the advanced settings of the app and I have "require app secret" disabled. Any ideas there?

Comment: @user13286 It might be that you're using an ancient version of the SDK. `Facebook\Facebook` is old syntax.

Comment: I ended up generating a temporary access token (~1 hour expiration) and then I used the debugger tool to extend the expiration and now it is working correctly. Thank you again for your help!